# Retrieve column info from next column

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is working but I figure I could enlist some help to make it more efficient. However before I show the query I would like to get a few answer on how others would do this.

What the query is supposed to do is to select data from a table, however some of the data is calculated within the `SELECT` statement. One of those calculations is the retreival of data from the next row. For example, I select a date from the current record, but I also want to know the next row's date as well.

Sample data:

```
=======================
date        |   comment
=======================
2013-01-01  |   comment
2013-03-03  |   comment
```

Desired output:

```
    
======================================
date        |   leadDate   |   comment
======================================
2013-01-01  |   2013-03-03 |   comment
2013-03-03  |     null     |   comment
```

Right now  I am using a `stored function` and a `cursor` to get this info and I tried using a `LEFT JOIN` which messed up my variables I am using.

I just wanted to get input from others on how they would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of **next** or **previous** rows makes sense **only** in the presence of explicitly specified `ORDER BY` clause.

Now assuming that you need your resultset ordered by `date` you can achieve your goal either by using a subquery

```
SELECT date,
      (
        SELECT date
          FROM table1
         WHERE date > t.date
         ORDER BY date
         LIMIT 1
      ) leadDate,
       comment
  FROM table1 t;
```

or by leveraging user(session) variables

```
SELECT date, leadDate, comment
  FROM
(
  SELECT date, CAST(@d AS DATE) leadDate, @d := date, comment
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @d := NULL) i
   ORDER BY date DESC
) q
 ORDER BY date;
```

Sample output (in both cases):

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| date       | leadDate   | comment  |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2013-01-01 | 2013-03-03 | comment1 |
| 2013-03-03 | NULL       | comment2 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb5a0/8)** demo